# Service with the ServiceNotification option

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, windows-services, messagebox

In Windows Vista and up, services can no longer access the GUI. However, after writing a simple mechanism to pass messages from my service to a helper GUI application, I found the following overload for `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show`, where the "MessageBoxOptions" parameter caught my eye:

```
public static DialogResult Show(
    string text,
    string caption,
    MessageBoxButtons buttons,
    MessageBoxIcon icon,
    MessageBoxDefaultButton defaultButton,
    MessageBoxOptions options
)
```

Looking at the enum more closely, one of the valid options is `MessageBoxOptions.ServiceNotification`, which states on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messageboxoptions.aspx) that:

> The message box is displayed on the active desktop. The caller is a
>   service notifying the user of an event. The function displays a
>   message box on the current active desktop, even if there is no user
>   logged on to the computer.

Does this mean that by passing the `MessageBox.Show()` method this option, my service can actually handle displaying a simple message from the service without having to use a helper application in Vista, Windows 7, and up?

Comment: Why do you even want an messagebox in a service ?

Comment: There are some fatal exceptions we want the end user to know about as they happen, so they don't have to dig through the log files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MESSAGEBOXOPTIONS ENUM DEMYSTIFIED - Applicable for XP](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2004/12/03/488.aspx)

> Starting with Windows Vista and above, user interfaces generated by Windows services can’t be seen. And even worst, your service could be stuck waiting for some user input that the user cannot give as she does not see anything

From [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yvesdolc/archive/2009/08/20/do-you-still-use-the-messagebox-api-in-your-windows-service.aspx)

---

To display MessageBox in windows service, you need to send  [`WTSSendMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683502%28VS.85%29.aspx) message. It will show up DialogBox in [Session 0 special desktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756986.aspx).

Comment: What about executing "net send" for XP or "msg" for Vista/Windows 7? Those aren't blocking commands and could easily be used to inform all users that something is wrong with the service. Even though I hate using terminal commands in code...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried using WTSSendMessage which works, but it's not an ideal scenario if the service is running on a server where multiple people might be logged in. I ended up just using my helper since it was already done anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you're proposing will work, but do you really want to do that? Remember that by default MessageBox.Show() is a **blocking** operation. Generally it's a really bad practice to have services waiting on UI operations.

The answer to your question is: "yes, but please don't."

Comment: Well if I throw the call to MessageBox.Show() into another thread that only runs that call, then it doesn't block the main thread. And we only want to display a message for critical messages that stem from an operation which will cause the service to crash, or issues preventing the service from starting.

Comment: Also I just tested this, it doesn't seem to work on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Your Service can display a MessageBox using Show method only if you have started "Interactive Service Detection" service. To start this Service type "services.msc" in the Run Window.

Comment: This is no longer an option for Windows 10.  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/interactive-services-detection-lostmissing-in/fb93b7ca-a74c-4075-b231-70aa65d8d6cc